# Group entries and get lowest and highest values within group

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that contains data that looks similar to this:

```
{ processName: "TestImport", processId: 1, message: "Started", time: 1486609206370 }
{ processName: "TestImport", processId: 1, message: "Finished",
time: 1486609207388 }
{ processName: "TestImport", processId: 2, message: "Started", time: 1486779281773 }
{ processName: "TestImport", processId: 2, message: "Finished",
time: 1485992810029}
{ processName: "SomeOtherImport", processId: 1, message: "Started", time: 1486779281773 }
{ processName: "SomeOtherImport", processId: 1, message: "Finished",
time: 1487993829281 }
```

So it basically contains multiple messages from different processes. Each process is identified via it's `processName` and a consecutive `processId`.

Now I want to make a query that selects the latest process, so the one with the highest ID and returns the time of the earliest and the last message, as well as the last message.

I have come close to this by using `aggregate` and grouping it like this:

```
db.status_history.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                name: "$processName",
                id: "$processId"
            },
            processId: {
                $last: "$processId"
            },
            message: {
                $last: "$message"
            },
            startTime: {
                $first: "$time"
            },
            endTime: {
                $last: "$time"
            }
        }
    }]);
```

But like this, I do not only get the entry with the highest ID for each process, but one entry for each ID (with the correct values though):

```
{ processName: "TestImport", processId: 1, message: "Finished", startTime: 1486609206370, endTime: 1486609207388 }
{ processName: "TestImport", processId: 2, message: "Finished", startTime: 1486779281773, endTime: 1485992810029 }
{ processName: "SomeOtherImport", processId: 1, message: "Finished", startTime: 1486779281773, endTime: 1487993829281 }
```

What do I need to change so that I will only get results for respectively the highest ID? Like this:

```
{ processName: "TestImport", processId: 2, message: "Finished", startTime: 1486779281773, endTime: 1486923811716 }
{ processName: "SomeOtherImport", processId: 1, message: "Finished", startTime: 1486779281773, endTime: 1487993829281 }
```

Comment: Try adding a sort `{$sort:{"processId":-1 ,"timestamp":1}}` before group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After first group can apply *sort by name and id* and then again *group by name* and select first matching information.

```
db.status_history.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                name: "$processName",
                id: "$processId"
            },
            processId: {$last: "$processId"},
            message: {$last: "$message"},
            startTime: {$first: "$time"},
            endTime: {$last: "$time"}
        }
    },
    {$sort:{"_id.name":1, "_id.id":-1}},
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.name",
            processId: {$first: "$processId"},
            message: {$first: "$message"},
            startTime: {$first: "$startTime"},
            endTime: {$first: "$endTime"}
        }
    }
]);
```